# if the date is same just display one time

Tags: php

if the date is same with database date just display one time only.Example:database date 16/2 then all 16/2 must display in a box, but other date also need to display. who help me to solve this problem.

```
   <h1>Payment Record</h1>
<?php

        $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `confirm_order` where customer = '$user_check'";
        $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {   

            ?>

            <table style="width:100%;border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:20px;">

            <tr>
                <td>Product Name: <?php echo $row['product_name'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity: <?php echo $row['quantity']?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Receiver Name: <?php echo $row['receiver_name']?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Receiver Address: <?php echo $row['receiver_address']?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Receiver Contact: <?php echo $row['receiver_contact']?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="float:right">Date: <?php echo $row['date']?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

        <?php   


        }       
?>
```

Example

```
id | product | date |
---|---------|------|
1  | book    | 16/2 |
2  | pencil  | 16/2 |
3  | shoe    | 18/2 |
```

Result

```
-------
book   |
pencil |
-------
shoe   |
-------
```

Comment: `must display in a box`-> what do you mean byt this? You are creating table so what actually you want now?

Comment: a little more explanation is needed

Comment: Example : database date1 = 12/6   date2 = 14/6   then the same date display in a table other date display to other table

Comment: my database date type is using timestamp

Comment: What result are you getting in $row?

Comment: Example: 12/6 have 2 item i need put them in a table

Comment: i getting all the user payment record

Comment: Your code is incomplete/wrong. As you stated _my database date type is using timestamp_ then in the table example is used format _16/2_ however your PHP code or SQL query does not manipulate the format and prints directly the value from database _echo $row['date']_ . Do more effort to prepare valid code you used and make your question more accurate and understandable.

Comment: thank ino suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution:

```
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `confirm_order` where customer = '$user_check'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$current_date=NULL;
$previous_date=NULL;
$table_open="<table border='1'>";
$table_close="</table><hr>";

$output=NULL;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $current_date=$row['date']; 

    if ($current_date==$previous_date) {            
        // SAME DATE
        $output.= "<tr><td>SAME DATE</td><td>".$current_date."</td></tr>";
        } else {
        // NEW DATE
        if ($previous_date<>NULL) {
            $output.= $table_close;
        }
        $output.= $table_open."<tr><td>NEW DATE</td><td>".$current_date."</td></tr>";
    }   
    $previous_date=$row['date'];
}    

echo $output;
```

Comment: i getting same result

Comment: I added a couple of <hr> and <br> to format better the results, you should use the same logic to create your tables

Comment: Well, I added also the table instead of <br> and <hr> I think this is exaclty what you need

Comment: echo "Product Name:".$product_name.$current_date.";  if i using this code only display 1 item only